# How to give end loop value in imacro

Tags: imacros

I am unable to find any function or any things in imacro where i can define last number in loop i.e. up to when loop has to run, I have started loop from row number 2 and want to end loop on 1500 row, so how i can give this (1500) value in imacro instead of manual filling, sugget the best way if anyone have the same, coding is:

```
TAB T=1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 999
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE XXXXXX.csv
SET !LOOP 2
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:search[order_nr] CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:{{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:refund_form ATTR=ID:refund_method CONTENT=XXXxX
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:refund_form ATTR=ID:remarks CONTENT=Done
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:refund_form ATTR=ID:submit
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to apply the Scripting Interface, try the following workaround:

```
TAB T=1
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 999
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE XXXXXX.csv

SET startLoop 2
SET maxLoop 1500
SET !LOOP EVAL(1-{{maxLoop}}+{{startLoop}})
SET normLoop EVAL({{!LOOP}}+{{maxLoop}}-1)

SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{normLoop}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=NAME:search[order_nr] CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=NAME:NoFormName ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TD ATTR=TXT:{{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SELECT FORM=ID:refund_form ATTR=ID:refund_method CONTENT=XXXxX
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTAREA FORM=ID:refund_form ATTR=ID:remarks CONTENT=Done
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ID:refund_form ATTR=ID:submit
```

Pay attention to the fact that you have to play this macro in **usual** (not loop) mode.